# Can R handle complex numbers

Tags: r, complex-numbers

I am confused how this works

```
> -2.2^(1-2.2)
[1] -0.3882333
```

But this does not

```
> x= -2.2
> x^(1+x)
[1] NaN
```

Comment: To answer your immediate question, the answer is "order of operations".

Comment: `x <- as.complex(-2.2); x^(1+x)`

Comment: R (1) needs to know that you want to solve in **C** (2), try with `x= -2.2 + 0i`. _Notes:_ (1) the program; (2) not the computer language, but the field of complex numbers.

Comment: @Brian: And you should read the entire R-FAQ included with all R installations in the help system. (Should be in the doc section .... doc/manual/R-FAQ.html ). This puzzle is a combination of  #7.33 and Joshua's pointer to the R function for creating complex numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use complex:
`

```
z <- complex(real = x, imaginary = y)

z

# [1] 1+1i
```

`

Source: http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2009/12/18/using-complex-numbers-in-r/

Comment: Oh, I see! So I can enter `z=complex(real=x)` and then just say `z^(1+z)` cool!